# Switch case with multiple values for the same case

Tags: flutter, dart, switch-statement

I would like to know the syntax to set a multiple case statement in a switch / case.
For example :

```
String commentMark(int mark) {
    switch (mark) {
        case 0 : // Enter this block if mark == 0
            return "Well that's bad" ;
        case 1, 2, 3 : // Enter this block if mark == 1 or mark == 2 or mark == 3
            return "Gods what happend" ;
        // etc.
        default :
            return "At least you tried" ;
    }
}
```

I cannot find the right syntax to set multiple case (the line `case 1, 2, 3 :`), is it even possible in Dart ?

I did not found any informations on pub.dev documentation, neither on dart.dev.

I tried :
    `case 1, 2, 3`
    `case (1, 2, 3)`
    `case (1 ; 2 ; 3)`
    `case (1 : 2 : 3)`
    `case 1 : 3`
and more !

Comment: try using 1...3

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Execution continues until it reaches a `break;`. Therefore, you can list cases one after the other to get the following code execute on either one of those cases.

```
String commentMark(int mark) {
    switch (mark) {
        case 0 : // Enter this block if mark == 0
            return "mark is 0" ;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3: // Enter this block if mark == 1 or mark == 2 or mark == 3
            return "mark is either 1, 2 or 3" ;
        // etc.
        default :
            return "mark is not 0, 1, 2 or 3" ;
    }
}
```

The `return` statements above serve to get out of the function. If you do not want to `return`, you have to use `break;` after each block, of course. This code below is equivalent to the one above.

```
String commentMark(int mark) {
    String msg;
    switch (mark) {
        case 0 : // Enter this block if mark == 0
            msg = "mark is 0" ;
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3: // Enter this block if mark == 1 or mark == 2 or mark == 3
            msg = "mark is either 1, 2 or 3" ;
            break;
        // etc.
        default:
            msg = "mark is not 0, 1, 2 or 3" ;
            break; // this is a good habit, in case you change default to something else later.
    }
    return msg;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Dart 3.0 have Pattern feature which you can use to make it simple.

For details see the documentation Link https://dart.dev/language/patterns

**Solution 1:**

```
String commentMark(int mark) {
    return switch (mark) {
        0 => "mark is 0",
        1 || 2 || 3 => "mark is either 1, 2 or 3",
        _ => "mark is not 0, 1, 2 or 3"
   };
}
```

print(commentMark(2)) ;

**Solution 2:**

```
  String commentMark(int mark) {
      switch (mark) {
        case 0:
          return "mark is 0";
        case 1 || 2 || 3:
          return "mark is either 1, 2 or 3";
        default:
         return "mark is not 0, 1, 2 or 3";
      }
  }
```

print(commentMark(3));

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiple case we can use or operator in single switch case it self.

```
switch (date) {
        case 1 | 21 | 31:
            return "st";
        case 2 | 22:
            return "nd";
        case 3 | 23:
            return "rd";
        default:
            return "th";
        }
```

Comment: In Dart, `case 1 | 21 | 31:` is equivalent to `case 31:` because `1 | 21 | 31` is evaluated as 31. So the case statement doesn't match the numbers `1` and `21`.

Comment: This case will not work. In this, all cases are considered as the last value. So Instead of this, you should write all cases separately. And use break; after the all cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple cases you should use below syntax:

```
     switch (yourCase) {    
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3: 
                  // Enter this block if yourCase == 1 or yourCase == 2 or yourCase == 3
                var msg = "your code to for cases either 1, 2 or 3" ;
                break;
            case 4: 
                  // Enter this block if yourCase == 4
                break;
                  }
```