# Is there a better way to write a nested if-else such as this?

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement

Below is a snippet of code for a flutter function returning a widget. It either returns a button or text widget depending on four different variables.

```dart
Widget _renderReservationState() {
          if (reservationsDetailState.isFinished == false) {
            if (reservationsDetailState.rsvpStatus == "Attending") {
              if (reservationsDetailState.attendanceStatus == "Attended") {
                return Center(
                    child: Text("Registration completed");)
              } else {
                if (reservationsDetailState.isEditing == false) {
                  return SizedBox(
                      child: Button(
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (myReservationsDetailState.isEditing) {
                              _setEditMode(false);
                            } else {
                              _setEditMode(true);
                            }
                          },
                          title: "Edit reservation"),
                      width: double.infinity);
                } else {
                  return SizedBox(
                      child: Button(
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (reservationsDetailState.isEditing) {
                              _confirmReservation(dateController.text,
                                  timeController.text, attendeeController.text);
                            } else {
                              _setEditMode(true);
                            }
                          },
                          title: "Confirm reservation"),
                      width: double.infinity);
                }
              }
            } else {
              return SizedBox(
                  child: Button(
                      onPressed: () => {
                            _confirmReservation(dateController.text,
                                timeController.text, attendeeController.text),
                          },
                      title: "Make a reservation"),
                  width: double.infinity);
            }
          } else {
            if (myReservationsDetailState.attendanceStatus == "Attended") {
              return Center(
                child: Text("Thank you for your visit")
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                  child: Text("Please join next time");)
            }
          }
        }
```

The existing code was a nested if-else over a couple hundred lines. I've refactored it to be shorter but I'm not happy with this implementation either.

Comment: not sure if you can in this language: Make `rsvpStatus`, `attendanceStatus` proper enums, use `switch` when you can.

Comment: I might use `enum` in  this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general advice on improving readability:

- Get rid of unnecessary `if` checks:

  ```dart
  if (someCondition) {
    _setEditMode(false);
  } else {
    _setEditMode(true);
  }
  ```

  is equivalent to just:

  ```dart
  _setEditMode(!someCondition);
  ```
- Avoid `if (condition == false)`.  If `condition` is non-nullable, use `if (!condition)`.
- Collapse nested `if` blocks into `if`-`else if` chains when possible:

  ```dart
  if (condition1) {
    ...
  } else {
    if (condition2) {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
  ```

  can be unindented a level to be:

  ```dart
  if (condition1) {
    ...
  } else if (condition2) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
  ```
- Don't write top-heavy `if`-`else` blocks.  Code like:

  ```dart
  if (condition1) {
    imagine();
    that();
    there();
    are();
    many();
    many();
    many();
    lines();
    ofCode();
    if (condition2) {
      withNested();
      blocks();
    } else {
      that();
      require();
      scrolling();
    }
  } else {
    someSingleLineOfCode();
  }
  ```

  is usually harder to follow than inverting the condition and putting the much shorter block on top:

  ```dart
  if (!condition1) {
    someSingleLineOfCode();
  } else {
    imagine();
    that();
    there();
    are();
    many();
    many();
    many();
    lines();
    ofCode();
    if (condition2) {
      withNested();
      blocks();
    } else {
      that();
      require();
      scrolling();
    }
  }
  ```
- Unindent `else` blocks by taking advantage of early exits:

  ```dart
  if (condition1) {
    return someWidget;
  } else {
    lots();
    of();
    other();
    code();
    return someOtherWidget;
  }
  ```

  can be:

  ```dart
  if (condition1) {
    return someWidget;
  }

  lots();
  of();
  other();
  code();
  return someOtherWidget;
  ```
- Try to emphasize which parts are the same across cases and which parts are different.  Examples:

  ```dart
  if (myReservationsDetailState.attendanceStatus == "Attended") {
    return Center(child: Text("Thank you for your visit"));
  } else {
    return Center(child: Text("Please join next time"));
  }
  ```

  can become:

  ```dart
    return Center(
        child: Text(myReservationsDetailState.attendanceStatus == "Attended"
            ? "Thank you for your visit"
            : "Please join next time"));
  ```

  For the section with multiple, similar `SizedBox(child: Button(...))` cases, I would create local variables to capture the differences and rearrange the code so that the common structure is shared.

Putting it all together:

```dart
Widget _renderReservationState() {
  if (reservationsDetailState.isFinished) {
    return Center(
        child: Text(myReservationsDetailState.attendanceStatus == "Attended"
            ? "Thank you for your visit"
            : "Please join next time"));
  }

  if (reservationsDetailState.rsvpStatus == "Attending" &&
      reservationsDetailState.attendanceStatus == "Attended") {
    return Center(child: Text("Registration completed"));
  }

  VoidCallback onButtonPressed;
  String buttonTitle;
  if (reservationsDetailState.rsvpStatus != "Attending") {
    onButtonPressed = () => _confirmReservation(
        dateController.text, timeController.text, attendeeController.text);
    buttonTitle = "Make a reservation";
  } else if (!reservationsDetailState.isEditing) {
    onButtonPressed = () => _setEditMode(!myReservationsDetailState.isEditing);
    buttonTitle = "Edit reservation";
  } else {
    onButtonPressed = () {
      if (reservationsDetailState.isEditing) {
        _confirmReservation(
            dateController.text, timeController.text, attendeeController.text);
      } else {
        _setEditMode(true);
      }
    };
    buttonTitle = "Confirm reservation";
  }

  return SizedBox(
      child: Button(onPressed: onButtonPressed, title: buttonTitle),
      width: double.infinity);
}
```

which is still ugly, but it has significantly less indentation, and in my opinion is better than it was originally.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a great use of union types. Let me try to compare it to `if`s and `switch`es.

When there are a combination of values for which you have to act in various different ways, it is sometimes inevitable to end up with code like this. You options here are:

1. Nested `if` statements like you have done
2. Nested `switch` statements
3. Using union types with a package such as [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#when).

Let's think about the pros and cons of each:

1. **Nested `if` statements**:

- Easy to get started with
- Least amount of indentation
- (!) Grouping cases with `||` is somewhat awkward
- (!) Easy to forget some cases
- (!) Have to remember to edit code when new cases appear

2. **Nested `switch` statements**:

- Relatively easy to type
- Can group cases [easily and clearly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58817926/switch-case-with-multiple-values-for-the-same-case/58817942#58817942)
- (!) Extra levels of indentation
- (!) Cases share local variables
- With enums, IDEs can provide warnings for missing cases. So the following two can be alleviated

  - (!) Easy to forget some cases
  - (!) Have to remember to edit code when new cases appear

3. **Union types**

- Forces you to cover all cases. Makes it a compile-time error to forget cases.
- When new cases are added, existing code cannot compile until you cover the new case everywhere.
- Cases become objects rather than simple values, you can add extra responsibilities to them.
- (!) Grouping of cases is not possible with freezed, there is a single "others" case with `orElse`.
- (!) Extra levels of indentation and extra closure syntax
- (!) Requires an extra step. With freezed you have to create those clasess and run build_runner to generate code.

I believe these are the main options. When you are in this situation and you feel uneasy that you or a teammate can forget a case someday, it's probably a good idea to give [union classes with freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#when) a try. Despite its inconveniences, the piece of mind about covering all cases that it provides is invaluable.

Borrowing examples from the package, when you have a union class with different cases like this:

```
@freezed
class Union with _$Union {
  const factory Union(int value) = Data;
  const factory Union.loading() = Loading;
  const factory Union.error([String? message]) = ErrorDetails;
}
```

You use it like this. Not providing any of the parameters in `when` is a compile-time error. So you can be sure that you will not forget any case:

```
var union = Union(42);

print(
  union.when(
    (int value) => 'Data $data',
    loading: () => 'loading',
    error: (String? message) => 'Error: $message',
  ),
); // Data 42
```

In your case, you can either create separate union types for each variable, or a single union type that represents the combination of these variables. So you can either have

```
@freezed
class IsFinished with _$IsFinished {
  const factory IsFinished.finished() = Finished;
  const factory IsFinished.notFinished() = NotFinished;
}
@freezed
class RsvpStatus with _$RsvpStatus {
  const factory RsvpStatus.none() = None;
  const factory RsvpStatus.rsvpd() = Rsvpd;
  const factory RsvpStatus.canceled() = Canceled;
}
// usage
Widget w = isFinished.when(
  finished: () => isRsvpd.when(
    none: () => Text('finished and no rsvp'),
    rsvpd: () => Text('finished and rsvpd'),
    cancelled: () => Text('finished and canceled'),
  ),
  notFinished: () => isRsvpd.when(
    none: () => Text('not finished and no rsvp'),
    rsvpd: () => Text('not finished and rsvpd'),
    cancelled: () => Text('not finished and canceled'),
  ),
);
```

or one single freezed class that has entries such as `finishedRsvpd`. In either case, forgetting a case will be a compile-time error and you will feel more at ease about your code.

Answer (score 0):

You will do yourself a favor and improve the readability of the code substantially if you split it up into many smaller functions or CustomWidgets. That way you can get rid of the extreme, unreadable nesting.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the most readable solution. Perhaps I got tunnel visioned by the previous implementation and tried to do it all in one function also.

Comment: Let me cite chapter 3:Functions from the book "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin: "This also implies that functions should not be large enough to hold nested structures. Therefore, the indent level of a function should not be greater than one or two. This, of course, makes the functions easier to read and understand". I really like the book, find it to be an extremely valuable read by the way so if you do not know it I can highly recommend it.